# How much per cent of bolts are shorter than $69$mm, how much are longer than $73$mm?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> A machine produces bolts such that the length $X$ of the bolts $X \sim
> N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = 70$mm and $\sigma = 2$mm.
>
> How much per cent of bolts are shorter than $69$mm, how much are
>   longer than $73$mm?

Hi math people. I need to know how to solve these types of problems for a test next week.

I think its crucial to detect what kind of distribution this is. It looks like normal distribution.

Shorter than $69$mm:

$P(X < 69) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{69-70}{2}\right) = P(X_{st} \leq -\frac{1}{2}) = \Phi(-0.5) = 1-\Phi(0.5) = 1-0.692 = 
\\=0.308  =30.8\text{%}$

---

Longer than $73$mm:

$P(X > 73) = 1-P(X \leq 73) = 1-P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{73-70}{2}\right) = 1-P(X_{st} \leq \frac{3}{2}) = 1-\Phi(1.5) = \\= 1-0.933 = 0.067 = 6.7\text{%}$

---

Am i correct?

Comment: You said $\mu = 70$mm and $\sigma = 2$mm. So why aren't the limits **68 mm** and **72 mm**?

Comment: Yes, this looks completely correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane If it were 68 and 72 then both would give the same answer. I don't think it is intended to be the same question, I think the test wants to ask 2 different questions.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you for confirm all!!!! Can maybe also check my other question is similar with this question pls https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546719/normal-distribution-choose-mu-such-that-only-10-of-bolts-are-shorter-than

Comment: @conime sure, I put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

(I wrote this answer as community wiki so the question can be marked as answered.)