# Normal distribution: Choose $\mu$ such that only $10$% of bolts are shorter than $70$mm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> A machine produces bolts such that the length $X$ of the bolts $X \sim
> N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = 70$mm and $\sigma = 2$mm.
>
> How much does $\mu$ need to be such that only $10$% of the bolts are
>   shorter than $70$mm? (where $\sigma$ stays same)

Ok I have idea do it like this:

We have $P(X < 70) = 0.1 = 1-\Phi(0.08) = \Phi(-0.08)= P(X_{st} \leq -0.08)$

where $X_{st} \leq \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ where $X = 70, \space\space\space\space \sigma= 2, \space\space\space\space X_{st}= -0.08$

Form this to $\mu$:

$$X_{st} \cdot \sigma \leq X-\mu$$

$$\Leftrightarrow X_{st} \cdot \sigma -X \leq -\mu$$

$$\Leftrightarrow -X_{st} \cdot \sigma +X \geq \mu$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 0.08 \cdot 2 + 70 \geq \mu $$

$$\Leftrightarrow 70.16 \geq \mu$$

Answer: You need set $\mu= 70.16$mm such that only $10$% of bolts are shorter then $70$mm.

But when I read the answer I think it all don't maked sense..?

What is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Phi(0.08)\ne 0.9$$ This is where the mistake appears to be - I don't see where you got $0.08$ from. I think that the correct value has $0.9=\Phi(1.282)$. In this case you'd get $\mu=72.564$, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where the first equality came from. Let $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Prove yourself the following

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X<x) = \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align}
Where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. The reason for this transform is that the standard normal quantiles are in the tables (statistical compandium). So you actually want to know for which $\mu$ we have:
\begin{align}
0.1 = \mathbb{P}(X<70) = \Phi\left( \frac{70-\mu}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Look it up in the tables or just compute it via a software what $\Phi^{-1}(0.1)$ must be. Do the rest of the calculation yourself. The $\mu$ you should get is around $72.6$.